Can a differentiable function be nowhere locally $\alpha$-Hölder for all $\alpha > 0$?
Does there exist a real valued function on $[0, 1]$ that is differentiable everywhere, but for every $\alpha > 0$ is nowhere locally $\alpha$-Hölder continuous? That is, it is not $\alpha$-Hölder on any open subinterval.
I hope I am not overlooking something elementary, but to my utmost surprise I actually think this might be true…
The answer by user479223 here shows that such a function can be differentiable almost everywhere, in fact even increasing and continuous.
PS: Wouldn't it be funny if there was also a function that was Holder continuous of every order less than 1, but nowhere differentiable…

There is something that is buzzing in my head and says:- "Dini continuity is the key concept here", but I cannot figure out if this is true or it is just a buzz.

No, such a function does not exist. In general, there is no differentiable function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with derivative unbounded in any open interval. If that was possible, we could construct by recursion two sequences of points $x_n<y_n$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that

$[x_{n+1},y_{n+1}]\subseteq(x_n,y_n)$.
$\lim_n\frac{|f(y_n)-f(x_n)|}{|y_n-x_n|}=\infty$.

Now let $p$ be the limit of the sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$. Note that $x_n<p<y_n$ for all $n$, and for all $n$, $\frac{|f(y_n)-f(x_n)|}{|y_n-x_n|}\leq\max\left(\frac{|f(p)-f(x_n)|}{|p-x_n|},\frac{|f(y_n)-f(p)|}{|y_n-p|}\right)$ (proof by picture). So by condition 2 above, $f$ cannot be differentiable at $p$.

Hmm, doesn’t $x^2 \sin (1/x^3)$ have unbounded derivative near 0?

Indeed, $x^2\sin(1/x^3)$ has unbounded derivative near $0$. In case that is the confusion, by "locally unbounded" I mean "unbounded in every open interval"

Ahh understood.

So the set of points $x\in[0,1]$ such that  $f’$ is not locally bounded at $x$ is a  closed set with empty interior,  and in fact any closed set with empty interior $C\subset[0,1]$ is the set of points $x\in[0,1]$ such that  $f’$ is not locally bounded at $x$ for some everywhere differentiable $f:[01,\to\mathbb R$

@PietroMajer yes, that is a nice statement. I guess you can obtain such $f$ by introducing one small copy of the function $x^2\sin(1/x^3)$ in each of the extremes of the (countably many) gaps of the set $C$

@PietroMajer and of course on the complement, which is a union of open intervals, it is Lipschitz with fixed constant on each open interval. This is a pretty neat decomposition result.

Yes, and multiplying everything by $dist(x,C)^2$ so that f'=0 on C.

btw the existence of a nested sequence of intervals with unbounded incremental ratio is also what one gets assuming f′≤0
a.e. and f
not decreasing.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/471848/is-the-w1-infty-limit-of-differentiable-functions-also-differentiable#comment1228373_471848
